# Getting "Cannot GET /" error on browser when trying to make a get request with mongodb mongoose

Tags: mongodb, post, server, router, mern

I'm building a mern-stack website. When I try to make a post request to list all my events, I see "Cannot POST /events" error, when I make get request, I see "Cannot GET /Events".

When I look at inspect, the more detailed error is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) localhost/:1"
I think there might be some problems with router..

Any suggestions/advice is appreciated.

I can successfully connect to mongoDB and localhost3000.

[image]

I already have my front-end done, if I'm not trying to connect to the server, everything shows fine. If I start my server, "Cannot GET /" error will show:

[image]

When I test in insomnia, same thing happens:

[image]

This is my server file:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
 
//middlewear
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri);
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})


const eventsRouter = require('./routes/events');

app.use('events', eventsRouter);


app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
    
});
```

This is router file, event.js where I make API calls:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
 
//middlewear
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri);
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})


const eventsRouter = require('./routes/events');

app.use('events', eventsRouter);


app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
    
});
```

This is how I implement front-end routers:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="App">
     <NavbarComp/>
        <Routes>
            <Route path = "/" element = {<Home/>} />
            <Route path = "/events" element = {<Events/>} />
            <Route path = "/balloon" element = {<Balloon/>} />
            <Route path = "/flower" element = {<Flower/>} />
            <Route path = "/grabAndGo" element = {<GrabAndGo/>}/>
        </Routes>
    </div>
     <Footer/>
 
    </Router>
  );
}
```

navbar:

```
export default class NavbarComp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
 
    <div>
        <Navbar expand="lg" className="bg-body-tertiary">
        <Container>
            <Navbar.Brand as = {Link} to = {"/"}>Boston_GG_Events</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="me-auto">
                <Nav.Link as = {Link} to = {"/"}> Home</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link as = {Link} to = {"/events"}>Events</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link as = {Link} to = {"/balloon"}>Balloon</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link as = {Link} to = {"/flower"}>Flower</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link as = {Link} to = {"/grabAndGo"}>Grab and Go</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
        </Navbar>
    </div>
    

)
  }
}
```

This is how I construct folder directories:

[image]

I tried to use insomnia to make post/get request, it should list all events in JSON file that I already created in mongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved. I shouldn't use the same port for front-end and back-end.